# How can I create dynamic ssl certificate key location in nginx conf file?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-config

I have many domain names folder in `/etc/letsencrypt/live/` this location with cert pem and cert key file. I want to serve any type of domain SSL key that in my `/etc/letsencrypt/live/` directory and I programmatically add different domain in this directory.

my nginx.conf file

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name default_server;

     map "$host" $domain_name { ~(.*)\.(.*)\.(.*)$ $2.$3; }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain_name/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain_name/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    client_max_body_size 20M;
...
}
```

But when I request a domain I got the error. `No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/default_server/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file) while SSL handshaking`
So `$domain_name` variable not transletting correctly it turns into `default_server` . How can I achieve this type of things. Thank you!.

Comment: `map` is not allowed in the `server` block, so I am surprised that your server is starting. Also, `$host` is not available when Nginx needs to load the certificate. There is [an example](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl_certificate) in the documentation that uses `$ssl_server_name` as it is available during the initial handshake.

Comment: I fixed this by changing host to ssl_server_name . But the problem is it not get the dynamic host SSL location.